# conditional operator without second attribute

Tags: objective-c, conditional-operator

I have realized I'm not fully understand conditional operator when the second value is missing. Can anyone explain me (and paste equivalent with if-else statement) the following code:

```
if (self.root && [data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    data = [data objectForKey:self.root] ? : data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator with no first element, e.g.

```
 variable ?: anotherVariable
```

means the same as

```
 (variable != nil) ? variable : anotherVariable
```

[Here](http://toastmo.com/blog/2012/10/24/objective-c-tricks-number-1-ternary-operations/) is some nice explanation about ternary operator in Objective-C.

Comment: "Objective-C supports omitting the true side of the ternary operator when working with objects." thanks what was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

u can do like this

to avoid confusion we take your sample code as

```
   if (self.root && [data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    myData = [data objectForKey:self.root] ? : data;  
   }
```

u can replace it with

```
if (self.root && [data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
 {
      if([data objectForKey:self.root])
      {
             //if the condition is true (if data is non-nil)
             myData = [data objectForKey:self.root]
      }
      else
      {
           //goes for false (if data is nil)
          myData = data     
      }

 }
```

for your case it goes like below

```
   if (self.root && [data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
      myData = [data objectForKey:self.root] ? : data; //if the object found for key "self.root" then myData will hav the object for key "self.root" otherwise it "myData" hav "data" 
   }
```

lets take a simple example

```
//for example
 BOOL aBoolValue = NO;
 int num = (aBoolValue == YES) ? 100 : 50; //if aBoolValue is YES then num has 100 otherwise 50
//in the above example num contains 50
```